# font size of items inside navigation drawer not changing

Tags: android, styles, themes, navigation-drawer

I want to increase the font size of items inside activity_main_drawer.xml which is the items showing in menu of navigation drawer. I've tried changing inside  tag by adding
android:textSize="22dp"
I've also created "style" inside style.xml file

```
<style name="DrawerTextStyle" >
     <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
     <item name="android:textSize">40dp</item>
     <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
 </style>
```

then I apply to the activity_main_drawer.xml. but it doesn't take effect.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:showIn="navigation_view"
    android:theme="@style/DrawerTextStyle">

    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/author_nietzsche"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_person_black_48dp"
            android:title="Friedrich Nietzsche" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/author_rand"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_person_black_48dp"
            android:title="Ayn Rand" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/author_kant"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_person_black_48dp"
            android:title="Immanuel Kant" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/author_aurelius"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_person_black_48dp"
            android:title="Marcus Aurelius" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/author_descartes"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_person_black_48dp"
            android:title="Rene Descartes" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/author_schopenhauer"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_person_black_48dp"
            android:title="Arthur Schopenhauer" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/author_confucius"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_person_black_48dp"
            android:title="Confucius" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/author_russell"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_person_black_48dp"
            android:title="Bertrand Russell" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/author_sartre"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_person_black_48dp"
            android:title="Jean-Paul Sartre" />

    </group

</menu>
```

some people have suggested to assign it inside activity_main.xml. but that doesn't work either..

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer">

    </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView >
```

Comment: How did you end up solving this issue, if at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must apply this attribute:

```
android:theme="@style/DrawerTextStyle"
```

to the `NavigationView` and **not** to the menu,
but first change `dp` to `sp`:

```
<style name="DrawerTextStyle" >
     <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
     <item name="android:textSize">40sp</item>
     <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
 </style>
```

Comment: "android:textSize" seems to be applied to the text inside "app:headerLayout" not to the menu items.